# 2D subdivision surfaces - How to arrive at $B^1 = \large{\frac{A^0 +6B^0 +C^0}{8}}$?

Tags: geometry, spline

In the video ["Math and Movies (Animation at Pixar) - Numberphile", at around timecode 11:45](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mX0NB9IyYpU&feature=youtu.be&t=705), the following is said:

> Using the $1$, $2$, $1$ rule, you can see that $B^1 = \large{\frac{A^0  +6B^0  +C^0}{8}}$

How does one arrive at this please?

I wonder where the $6$ and the $8$ come into the picture.

Comment: That link isn't working for me.

Comment: @mr_e_man Fixed.